# Routeconstraint with Ninject and dbcontext

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I'm trying to build a constraint that checks against database. And I'm using Ninject, but for some reason it doesnt create a new instance of my repository when it fires.

global.asax.cs

```
// Content
routes.MapRoute(
        "Content Language Route",
        "{languageID}/List",
             new { controller = "Content", action = "Index",
             new { languageID = new LanguageRouteConstraint() },
             new string[] { "MyProj.MVC.Controllers" }
         ); 
.....
kernel.Bind<IContentRepository>().To<ContentRepository>();
```

Constraint

```
public class LanguageRouteConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
#region IRouteConstraint Members

private readonly IContentRepository _contentRepository;

public LanguageRouteConstraint(IContentRepository contentRepository)
{
     this._contentRepository = contentRepository;
}

public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
{
 if (routeDirection == RouteDirection.IncomingRequest)
 {
   string languageID = values["languageID"].ToString();

   if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(languageID))
     return false;

   MyProj.MVC.Models.Language language = _contentRepository.GetLanguage(languageID);

   return (language != null);
   }
  return false;
  }    
#endregion
}
```

Using Ninject for the repository works in the controller, but do I need to modify the route in gobal asa for it to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it like this:

```
 // Content
 routes.MapRoute("Content Language Route",
      "{languageID}/List",
      new { controller = "Content", action = "Index",
      new
      {
      languageID = new LanguageRouteConstraint(
            DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IContentRepository>())
      },
     new string[] { "MyProj.MVC.Controllers" }
 );
```